# Resolving Mixed Content Error when Sending HTTPS Requests to a Self-Signed CouchDB from a Cached PWA Web App in Offline Mode

Tags: http, https, couchdb, progressive-web-apps

I have a Progressive Web App (PWA) that is cached and runs offline. It sends HTTPS requests to a self-signed CouchDB server at https://localhost:6984. However, I'm encountering a "Mixed Content" error. How can I resolve this issue?

I've ensured that my PWA is set up to work offline, and I've already configured my CouchDB server to use HTTPS with a self-signed certificate. Despite these measures, I'm still facing Mixed Content errors when the PWA is offline. Can anyone provide guidance on how to fix this issue and establish a secure connection between my PWA and the CouchDB server even when offline? Thank you in advance for your assistance.

I attempted to add a localhost CA and apply an SSL certificate to CouchDB on port 6984. My expectation was to establish an HTTPS connection for secure communication.

And I added  to the request.